swap the js var node words for an html span list inside a div
I want to swap the words in the js, i want the words to come from a span word list inside a div, the source of this project is a codepen file, here is the link of the codepen file   https://codepen.io/controversial/pen/wWVGOv   I am not sure if editing this codepen file is allowed or not, but that is what I need to learn to do, thank you in advance.
   <div id="bubbles"></div>

    #bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {label: "Pop"},
  {label: "Alternative"},
  {label: "Rock"},
  {label: "Jazz"},
  {label: "Hits"},
  {label: "Dance"},
  {label: "Metal"},
  {label: "Experimental"},
  {label: "Rap"},
  {label: "Electronic"},
]);
var edges = new vis.DataSet();

var container = document.getElementById('bubbles');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};

var options = {
  nodes: {borderWidth:0,shape:"circle",color:{background:'#F92C55', highlight:{background:'#F92C55', border: '#F92C55'}},font:{color:'#fff'}},
  physics: {
    stabilization: false,
    minVelocity:  0.01,
    solver: "repulsion",
    repulsion: {
      nodeDistance: 40
    }
  }
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);


// Events
network.on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.nodes.length) {
    var node = nodes.get(e.nodes[0]);
    // Do something
    nodes.update(node);
  }
});

I try using Google's Bard and it froze and could not doit, I try perplexity and also could not doit.

Try the code below and find whether it fits your need.
First, target the div which contain the spans, in this case I use getElementById. Then, iterates each of the spans and gets the text using textContent. Then we add the text of each span to the node.


var nodes = new vis.DataSet();
var edges = new vis.DataSet();

var container = document.getElementById('bubbles');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};

var options = {
  nodes: {borderWidth:0,shape:"circle",color:{background:'#F92C55', highlight:{background:'#F92C55', border: '#F92C55'}},font:{color:'#fff'}},
  physics: {
    stabilization: false,
    minVelocity:  0.01,
    solver: "repulsion",
    repulsion: {
      nodeDistance: 40
    }
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

var labelDiv = document.getElementById('label-1');
var spans = labelDiv.querySelectorAll('span');

spans.forEach(function(span) {
  var label = span.textContent.trim();
  nodes.add({ label: label });
});

network.on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.nodes.length) {
    var node = nodes.get(e.nodes[0]);
    nodes.update(node);
  }
});
#bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis.min.js"></script>

<div id="bubbles"></div>
<div id="label-1" class="hidden">
  <span>Pop</span>
  <span>Alternative</span>
  <span>Rock</span>
  <span>Jazz</span>
  <span>Hits</span>
  <span>Dance</span>
  <span>Metal</span>
  <span>Experimental</span>
  <span>Rap</span>
  <span>Electronic</span>
</div>




Thank You ! Gedanggoreng  ... the code works GREAT ! I appreciate your help!

Glad to be of help. Pay it forward, will you?
